# What is the jquery unload event() equivalent (not deprecated) in new versions?

Tags: jquery

I need to check if a user leaves the current page. I understand .unload on jquery checks for this, but the method is deprecated now. What's the best alternative nowadays?

Comment: [`.on('unload')`](https://api.jquery.com/unload/) -- or the vanillaJS version, [`window.addEventListener('unload')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload)

Comment: It's the still 'unload'. However, you need event delegation instead of binding.

Comment: FYI: if you expect to send something to the server, it is going to be a race condition.

Answer (score -1):

In jQuery V 3.0 unload removed at all.

The [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/unload/) WebSite offer `.trigger( "unload" )` instead of `.unload()`.

It is  the best alternative nowadays

Comment: The asker needs to check if the user leave the page, not to trigger the event.

Thus the equivalent is  .on( "unload", handler )